# Lazy loaded Component / dynamic import - how to configure rollup, so bundled files are only created once?

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I'm trying to lazy load a Component and configure rollup to do so. I already made following adjustments

###### rollup.config.js

```
export default {
    output: {
        format: 'es', // before ->  'iife'
        dir: 'public/build' // before ->  file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

###### index.html

instead of import `bundle.js`

```
<script defer type="module" src='/build/main.js'></script>
```

There are then three files created inside build `main.js`, `main-93f53e7a.js` and `SomeComponent-5f7e94f4.js`

Functionality wise this seems to work - the two main files are loaded when opening the page, the one of the component only when the component is mounted

The problem is, that when running this in `dev mode` and changing something in the code, additional files are created for `main-*someSuffix*` and `SomeComponent-*someSuffix*`

What do I have to add to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see are probably the remnants of the previous build(s). Rollup does not empty the output directory when it starts a new build.

You can add this behaviour with a plugin, for example this one: [rollup-plugin-delete](https://github.com/vladshcherbin/rollup-plugin-delete).

`rollup.config.js`

```js
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'es'
  },
  plugins: [
    del({ targets: 'dist/**' }),
  ]
}
```